# MSAL Login: "Deserialization failed. Skipping AccountRecord" / "Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential" and getting result back takes quite long

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I am logging in to a B2C tenant via the official Android MSAL library and this code:

```
val signInParameters = SignInParameters.builder()
    .withScopes(scopes.toList())
    .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
    .withActivity(_currentActivity!!)
    .build()

_msalClient.signIn(signInParameters)
```

This shows the Chrome custom tab and I can successfully login. However I can find the following warnings in Logcat (and as one can see on the timestamps, getting the result back from MSAL takes roughly one second, which is quite long):

```
// just the warnings from MSAL:
The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
alternative_account_id was null.
Avatar URL was null.
The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
Deserialization failed. Skipping AccountRecord
Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential
Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential
Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential

// full logcat entries of the warnings
// first and last line are from my MSAL wrapper. 
// First line = MSAL activity destroyed,
// last line = MSAL authentication callback success
// besides the warnings, note the roughly one second that passes between the first and last line
12:36:21.754 MsalService              I  onActivityDestroyed
12:36:22.479 SchemaUtil               W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
12:36:22.479 SchemaUtil...eAccountId  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] alternative_account_id was null.
12:36:22.479 SchemaUtil:getAvatarUrl  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] Avatar URL was null.
12:36:22.480 SchemaUtil               W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
12:36:22.482 SchemaUtil               W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken.
12:36:22.483 SharedPref...ntialCache  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] Deserialization failed. Skipping AccountRecord
12:36:22.816 SharedPref...ntialCache  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential
12:36:22.823 SharedPref...ntialCache  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential
12:36:22.825 SharedPref...ntialCache  W  [2023-01-29 11:36:22 - thread_name: pool-4-thread-1, correlation_id: <removed> - Android 33] Deserialization failed. Skipping Credential
12:36:22.894 MsalServic...onCallback  I  MSAL: authenticationCallback onSuccess
```

What do these warnings mean and are they the reason that getting the result back takes so long (from 12:36:21.754 to 12:36:22.894)?